# Cannot get Google Earth to run in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

From where should we launch Google Earth in Ubuntu 12.04
We cannot get it to run, after successful download & install.
The site keeps putting one back to the information page.
G-E worked fine with previous versions.
What next?

Answer (score 0):

Single answer can not help you much , Ubuntu Community has provided a very good section

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GoogleEarth#Troubleshooting